# How to Deploy laravel application on Azure

Tags: azure

Hello? Does anyone know how to deploy a laravel application build with PHP 7.3 from github to Azure?
I tried a lot of things but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel application, uses the */public* subdirectory as the site root. The default PHP Docker image for App Service uses Apache, and it doesn't let you customize the `DocumentRoot` for Laravel. However, you can use `.htaccess` to rewrite all requests to point to */public* instead of the root directory. In the repository root, an `.htaccess` is added already for this purpose. With it, your Laravel application is ready to be deployed.

However, if you wish to [change the site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-language-php#change-site-root) root, you can update the `.htaccess` file in your repository root with the following content:

```
<IfModule  mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Check the [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/14561/how-to-deploy-php-laravel-application-on-azure-app.html) where the same discussion going on